# ora-12154 Visual studio dataset designer

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, ora-12154

This is crazy.  We develop app in VS2008 and the connection string pointing to oracle db (generated by a Dataset designer) allows to view table adapter's queries just fine at design time.  But when we hit F5 the stupid ora-12154 pops up and you can die or beat your head to death.  By the way toad, dbartisan work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That error code indicates your database service name is not correct.  That's probably because the Oracle client hasn't been configured correctly on the PC or you're using the wrong name.  Can you connect with sqlplus or any of the Oracle tools that came with the client?

Comment: What about toad or DBArtisan being able to work with Oracle server ok?